# Attempt to install QGIS 2.8 on Ubuntu 15.04 installs old version instead

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

I previously had installed QGIS 2.8 with the GRASS plugin on Ubuntu 14.04.  Through a chain of events I ended up having to do a clean install of Ubuntu 15.04, and am attempting to re-install QGIS 2.8.

I have followed the instructions on the QGIS install page:  my /etc/apt/sources.list is updated with the following lines:

```
deb (insert http header)qgis.org/ubuntugis vivid main
deb-src (insert http header)qgis.org/ubuntugis vivid main
deb (insert http header)ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu vivid main
```

My software ppa (displayed in the 'Other Software' tab of my "software and Updates" settings box) is set to "(insert http header)"
"ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu"

The signing key in my settings 'Authentication' tab reads 
"DD45F6C3 2014-08-19
QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2014) "

When I do an apt-get update followed by an apt-get install, however, it only downloads the old qgis 2.4 files.  There's nothing I can find in my sources.list that calls for 2.4.  How can I bypass the old software and make sure it downloads the new?

Answer (score 1):

This repo works for me:

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian vivid main
```

Please add it to your sources.list file.

You may also add qgis.org gpg keys:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv DD45F6C3

gpg --export --armor DD45F6C3 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=vivid the Ubuntugis unstable repo does not yet contain any packages for QGIS on Ubuntu Vivid 15.04.

In this case, you might get only the outdated package provided by Ubuntu.

So you have to use the [official QGIS repository](http://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) without ubuntugis dependencies, or wait until QGIS 2.10 which is just around the corner.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I just noticed that 2.10 is right on the verge of being released.  I won't be able to do anything with it until later in the week anyway, so perhaps the new version will be available then.

Comment: what is the difference between using a debian version and the one with ubuntugis dependencies? Both seem to work?

Comment: Ubuntugis usually has some more up-to-date GIS packages than the debian repository. Unfortunately, the one for Ubuntu 15.04/vivid only has 8 packages yet:https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable?field.series_filter=vivid